# How to build a conda package but exclude/omit/not include a specific folder/directory?

Tags: anaconda, package, conda, software-distribution

I'm trying to build a conda package but I just realized that it keeps adding all of my previous releases in tar ball.  I tried adding this line: `recursive-exclude releases/ *.tar.gz` to my `MANIFEST.in` but it isn't working.

#### Here is my build command:

````
(µ_env) jespinozlt-osx:Packages jespinoz$ cd soothsayer/
(µ_env) jespinozlt-osx:soothsayer jespinoz$ ls
Icon?           dist            releases
MANIFEST.in     docs            setup.py
README.md       install         soothsayer
bin         license.txt     soothsayer.egg-info
build           logo.png        standalone
devel.txt       meta.yaml       tutorials
(µ_env) jespinozlt-osx:soothsayer jespinoz$ conda build .
No numpy version specified in conda_build_config.yaml.  Falling back to default numpy value of 1.11
WARNING:conda_build.metadata:No numpy version specified in conda_build_config.yaml.  Falling back to default numpy value of 1.11
Adding in variants from internal_defaults
INFO:conda_build.variants:Adding in variants from internal_defaults
Attempting to finalize metadata for soothsayer
INFO:conda_build.metadata:Attempting to finalize metadata for soothsayer
BUILD START: ['soothsayer-py36_2019.12-0.tar.bz2']
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): ...working... done
Solving environment: ...working... done
Source cache directory is: /Users/jespinoz/anaconda3/conda-bld/src_cache
INFO:conda_build.source:Source cache directory is: /Users/jespinoz/anaconda3/conda-bld/src_cache
INFO conda_build.source:download_to_cache(43): Source cache directory is: /Users/jespinoz/anaconda3/conda-bld/src_cache
No hash (md5, sha1, sha256) provided for soothsayer_v2019.12.tar.gz.  Source download forced.  Add hash to recipe to use source cache.
WARNING:conda_build.source:No hash (md5, sha1, sha256) provided for soothsayer_v2019.12.tar.gz.  Source download forced.  Add hash to recipe to use source cache.
WARNING conda_build.source:download_to_cache(59): No hash (md5, sha1, sha256) provided for soothsayer_v2019.12.tar.gz.  Source download forced.  Add hash to recipe to use source cache.
Found source in cache: soothsayer_v2019.12.tar.gz
INFO:conda_build.source:Found source in cache: soothsayer_v2019.12.tar.gz
INFO conda_build.source:download_to_cache(63): Found source in cache: soothsayer_v2019.12.tar.gz
Extracting download
source tree in: /Users/jespinoz/anaconda3/conda-bld/soothsayer_1578343428831/work
export PREFIX=/Users/jespinoz/anaconda3/conda-bld/soothsayer_1578343428831/_h_env_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placeho
export SRC_DIR=/Users/jespinoz/anaconda3/conda-bld/soothsayer_1578343428831/work
Processing $SRC_DIR
Building wheels for collected packages: soothsayer
  Building wheel for soothsayer (setup.py): started
  Building wheel for soothsayer (setup.py): finished with status 'done'
  Stored in directory: /private/tmp/pip-ephem-wheel-cache-z5uej2un/wheels/93/2c/ae/23c5322c97f4ea4b77b566ff85638a1b92198cf0836e7fab90
Successfully built soothsayer
Installing collected packages: soothsayer
Successfully installed soothsayer-2019.12

Resource usage statistics from building soothsayer:
   Process count: 3
   CPU time: Sys=0:00:00.4, User=0:00:00.7
   Memory: 57.2M
   Disk usage: 4.2K
   Time elapsed: 0:00:04.1

Packaging soothsayer
INFO:conda_build.build:Packaging soothsayer
INFO conda_build.build:build(1551): Packaging soothsayer
Packaging soothsayer-py36_2019.12-0
INFO:conda_build.build:Packaging soothsayer-py36_2019.12-0
INFO conda_build.build:bundle_conda(890): Packaging soothsayer-py36_2019.12-0
No files or script found for output soothsayer
WARNING:conda_build.build:No files or script found for output soothsayer
WARNING conda_build.build:bundle_conda(970): No files or script found for output soothsayer
number of files: 0
Fixing permissions
Packaged license file/s.
TEST START: /Users/jespinoz/anaconda3/conda-bld/noarch/soothsayer-py36_2019.12-0.tar.bz2
Adding in variants from /var/folders/6z/5vbtz_gmkr76ftgc3149dvtr0003c0/T/tmp6matkfoy/info/recipe/conda_build_config.yaml
INFO:conda_build.variants:Adding in variants from /var/folders/6z/5vbtz_gmkr76ftgc3149dvtr0003c0/T/tmp6matkfoy/info/recipe/conda_build_config.yaml
INFO conda_build.variants:_combine_spec_dictionaries(189): Adding in variants from /var/folders/6z/5vbtz_gmkr76ftgc3149dvtr0003c0/T/tmp6matkfoy/info/recipe/conda_build_config.yaml
Nothing to test for: /Users/jespinoz/anaconda3/conda-bld/noarch/soothsayer-py36_2019.12-0.tar.bz2
Renaming work directory,  /Users/jespinoz/anaconda3/conda-bld/soothsayer_1578343428831/work  to  /Users/jespinoz/anaconda3/conda-bld/soothsayer_1578343428831/work_moved_soothsayer-py36_2019.12-0_osx-64_main_build_loop
# Automatic uploading is disabled
# If you want to upload package(s) to anaconda.org later, type:

anaconda upload /Users/jespinoz/anaconda3/conda-bld/noarch/soothsayer-py36_2019.12-0.tar.bz2

# To have conda build upload to anaconda.org automatically, use
# $ conda config --set anaconda_upload yes

anaconda_upload is not set.  Not uploading wheels: []
####################################################################################
Resource usage summary:

Total time: 0:01:52.0
CPU usage: sys=0:00:00.4, user=0:00:00.7
Maximum memory usage observed: 57.2M
Total disk usage observed (not including envs): 4.2K


####################################################################################
Source and build intermediates have been left in /Users/jespinoz/anaconda3/conda-bld.
There are currently 1 accumulated.
To remove them, you can run the ```conda build purge``` command
````

#### Here is my `MANIFEST.in` file:

```
(µ_env) jespinozlt-osx:soothsayer jespinoz$ cat MANIFEST.in
recursive-include soothsayer/io/data_type/ *.py
recursive-include soothsayer/feature_extraction/algorithms/ *.py
recursive-include soothsayer/r_wrappers/packages/ *.py
recursive-include soothsayer/tests/data/ *.py
recursive-include soothsayer/db/ *.pbz2
recursive-exclude releases/ *.tar.gz
global-exclude *.py[cod] __pycache__
```

I want to exclude the tar balls in this folder:

```
(µ_env) jespinozlt-osx:soothsayer jespinoz$ ls -lhS releases/
total 189456
-rwxrwxrwx@ 1 jespinoz  tigr    18M Jan  2 11:41 soothsayer_v2019.12.tar.gz
-rwxrwxrwx@ 1 jespinoz  tigr    18M Dec  2 10:57 soothsayer_v2019.11.tar.gz
-rwxrwxrwx@ 1 jespinoz  tigr    18M Nov  5 14:13 soothsayer_v2019.10.tar.gz
-rwxrwxrwx  1 jespinoz  tigr    10M Oct  2 11:26 soothsayer_v2019.09.tar.gz
-rwxrwxrwx@ 1 jespinoz  tigr    10M Sep  3 11:08 soothsayer_v2019.08.tar.gz
-rwxrwxrwx@ 1 jespinoz  tigr    10M Aug  8 16:33 soothsayer_v2019.07.tar.gz
-rwxrwxrwx@ 1 jespinoz  tigr   9.1M Jun 20  2019 soothsayer_v2019.06.tar.gz
-rw-r--r--@ 1 jespinoz  tigr   659B Jun 20  2019 create_release.sh
```

#### It's including all of my previous releases:

```
(µ_env) jespinozlt-osx:noarch jespinoz$ tar -xzf soothsayer-py36_2019.12-0.tar.bz2
(µ_env) jespinozlt-osx:noarch jespinoz$ ls -lh info/recipe/releases/
total 192776
-rw-r--r--  1 jespinoz  tigr   659B Jun 20  2019 create_release.sh
-rwxr-xr-x  1 jespinoz  tigr   9.1M Jun 20  2019 soothsayer_v2019.06.tar.gz
-rwxr-xr-x  1 jespinoz  tigr    10M Aug  8 16:33 soothsayer_v2019.07.tar.gz
-rwxr-xr-x  1 jespinoz  tigr    10M Sep  3 11:08 soothsayer_v2019.08.tar.gz
-rwxr-xr-x  1 jespinoz  tigr    10M Oct  2 11:26 soothsayer_v2019.09.tar.gz
-rwxr-xr-x  1 jespinoz  tigr    18M Nov  5 14:13 soothsayer_v2019.10.tar.gz
-rwxr-xr-x  1 jespinoz  tigr    18M Dec  2 10:57 soothsayer_v2019.11.tar.gz
-rwxr-xr-x  1 jespinoz  tigr    18M Jan  2 11:41 soothsayer_v2019.12.tar.gz
```

#### Here's my `meta.yml`

```
{% set name = "soothsayer" %}
{% set version = "2019.12" %}

package:
  name: {{ name|lower }}
  version: py36_{{ version }}

source:
  url: https://github.com/jolespin/{{ name }}/releases/download/v{{ version }}/soothsayer_v{{ version }}.tar.gz

build:
  noarch: python
  number: 0
  script: python -m pip install --no-deps --ignore-installed .

requirements:
  run:
    - python >=3.6,<3.7

about:
  home: https://github.com/jolespin/soothsayer
  license: BSD-3
  license_family: BSD
  license_file: license.txt
  summary: 'High-level package for (bio-)informatics'
  description: 'This module contains analytical tools and sophisticated plotting methods for informatics datasets.'
```

Comment: What is your `meta.yaml`?

Comment: I've added it in there.

Answer (score 0):

This is a workaround for whatever is going wrong here. You could always split out your build script into a file called build.sh and manually `rm -rf releases` at the end of it.

```
rm -rf $PREFIX/info/recipe/releases
```

Conda-build is simply making a tar archive of everything your script command is doing.  Although this is under info/recipe, so that might be the contents of your recipe directory.  I'd move your recipe into a subdir (conda.recipe) and run it out of there or you can tell conda-build (in the meta.yaml) to not include the recipe using a switch: `--no-include-recipe`